# Docker images are lost while pulling from Azure container registry to kubernetes node

Tags: kubernetes, docker-image, azure-container-registry

I could able to pull a docker image from a Azure container registry but after few hours or weeks or days the pulled images are lost in a kubernetes node. I couldn't see my pulled image if I do docker images in kubernetes node.

Comment: I don't think it's the problem of the ACR. You need to provide more details. And check if something or some task in the host that would delete data.

Comment: Yes, there is not a problem with ACR. What task that would be in deleting docker images from host machine ?

Comment: It depends on which machine you used. Generally, if the disk space is not enough, maybe some task will delete data to make more space.

Comment: please provide more info as to where you are downloading the docker images

Comment: On Kubernetes, Kubelet has a built in Image GarbageCollector which will clean up old / unused images for example.

Comment: How to setup a threshold for GarbageCollector ?
Is there a way to use docker images directly from Azure repo, without pulling to a kubernetes node as it is squeezing the memory space in a machine..

Comment: you want o use the image where ? if its to be in Kubernetes, you will have to pull on the node, before you can start the pod from that image.

Comment: you can look at extending your AKS cluster with ACI support if needs be.

Comment: Can space be extended in a host machine by softlinking kubelet or kubeadm to home directory ?